# What kind of sauce did I "invent"?

Tags: sauce, classification

One day I had an idea for a special "sauce" to use on (chicken) burgers. The basic idea was to give it some sort of "salad dressing" like taste.

The basic ingredients are cream cheese, mustard, vinegar and freshly ground black pepper. Plus a bit of salt and maybe some herbs I had lying around (mainly tarragon).

Now, I know I probably didn't invent something completely new, so my question is, what kind of sauce have I created? Are there similar widely known (named) ones?

Comment: Welcome to the site @HasAnIdea. Your question in confusing, and cannot be answered as it is. You made a sauce, which you already figured out, but you ask what you've created. You are asking ways to improve it, which is subjective as you haven't said what you'd like to improve.

Comment: @GdD, HadAnIdea has made a chicken sauce, and since he feels it is delicious, it cannot be his own invention, but must be a rediscovery of someone else's excellent sauce. He just wants to know the name of it. However considering its ingredients, I believe it may very well be his own original invention, and I think he should have the privilege of naming it. Also ... not sure it *can* be improved upon.

Comment: I guess it is a kind of cream cheese dip?

Comment: In some ways, it's like a mock sour cream .... creamy from the cream cheese, but thinned out and made sour from the vinegar.  Mustard and herbs starts to get us closer to one of the early recipes for beef Stroganoff.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you didn't over-use the vinegar, and mainteined the spreadable consistency of the cream-cheese, I think what you've invented is also known as a sandwich spread.

Answer (score -3):

When in doubt how to name anything, revert to the go-to language of cuisine: French and I would say:

#### Marriage de fromage, moutarde et herbes

(Marriage of cheese, mustard and herbs just *sounds* so much more sexy in French and black pepper is kind of a herb and you're not giving away the full recipe)

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I see the drive-by downvotes but don't see any  other solutions...  **:P**